# Linux Filesystem Backup Solution: SSD -> HDD

Tags: linux, backup

Under Linux,

I have an SSD as my main boot disk with about 50 GB or so of data, and a mostly empty 2TB HDD for bulk storage.

I would like to run a cron job periodically that does a full/incremental backup of my SSD's file system to my HDD.  I remember one of my old sysadmins used to use a Perl-based one that was very good and did an incremental backup using hard-links, but I can't remember the name of it (anyone?).  Or failing that can anyone recommend an appropriate package?

Comment: rsync is the way I'd go for this.

Comment: @Rob: rsync doesn't do incremental backup AFAIK?  I'd like to be able to go back some time period and get an older image, without having to do a full backup everytime.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Totally skipped a word, my bad. Some google searches turn up results for incremental backups with rsync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `rsnapshot`.  It uses rsync and hard links to efficiently copy only changes to the backup, and keep multiple directories that each appear to be a full backup, but unchanged files are hard linked so they don't take up more space.